# writing a program to detect if internet connection has been dsconnected?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I am using reliance Netconnect+ for internet connection. I am using windows 7 os. If the I plugin the netconnect+ device and connect to internet, it works fine. But when I leave the system for a long time the connection gets disconnected automatically.
 There is no setting for this. So is it possible to check the connection and if disconnected, connect it progrmattically (equivalent to a human pressing the connect button )?

Comment: Try a continuous ping, couple second interval or so, it might act as a keep-alive. You can also use autoit to take action based on ping results, so you can automate the reconnect if it does become disconnected.

Comment: @MaQleod : is it possible to take action - like press the connect button programmatically

Comment: Are you using a Dial-up system, broadband, wireless, LAN, PPoE, VPN?

Comment: @Luke : its a dial-up. When I plugin in the usb device. The reliance software shows up. In the settings, the username and password are prestored(so that I do no have to enter it again and again, unless I plug the device into a different pc). So all I have to do is press the connect button.

Comment: yes, though the method depends on the control itself. Here is a list of built-ins: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm

Comment: @MaQleod : I went through the autoit site. It requires BASIC programming knowledge. I have no idea about BASIC... however I have started the download

Comment: I have written a batch file for exact same purpose(I use BSNL connection)..
I don't have it with me right now....I'll post it as soon as possible..

Comment: @MaQleod : I have started using Autoit. I have encountered a problem. I posted it as a separate question - Please answer it if possible  http://superuser.com/questions/449396/get-window-focus-in-autoit

Comment: Are you using windows dial-up connection or reliance netconnect custom dialer.....my solution needs you to dial using windows dial-up networking..

Comment: @tumchaaditya : It is reliance netconnect custom dialer. I think BSNL also has its own software for the dial up?

Comment: I think you can use default dialer as well..
go to control panel> network and sharing center > in left pane, manage network connections....see if reliance connection is listed there..btw, have you tried ping google trick floating around the internet?

Comment: @tumchaaditya : pinging google, I can know if internet is activated or not. But I want to activate the internet connection if it has been disconnected. I think autoit is a good solution for that.

Comment: @MaQleod : If you can give your answer in the answer section (autoit), I will accept it. It might help others also.