# Get Window Focus in Autoit for Applications in System Tray

Tags: windows-7, autoit

I have two windows open and **not** minimized (Autoit help and RelianceNetconnect). And the current focus is with a Notepad file. This is my Autoit script :

```
DIM $s=WinActivate("AutoIt Help")
MsgBox(0,"Check",$s)
```

This works and the autoit jelp window come to focus. The Message Box prints this `0x00046ce`.

This is my second Autoit Script:

```
DIM $s=WinActivate("Reliance Netconnect")
MsgBox(0,"Check",$s)
```

This does not work, i.e the reliance netconnect window does not come to focus. The MessageBos Prints `0x002C01DC`. 
[This](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm) link says that `WinActivate` either returns the handle to the window requested if successful or returns 0 if failed.
 In my second case it returns a non zero value. Then why is the window not getting focused?

Comment: I'd only like to mention that 2C01DC *is the handle*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that "Reliance Netconnect" was a **System tray Application** i.e it resided in the system tray. You cannot use WinActivate to get their focus. they have to be redrawn. 
This worked for me

```
#Include <GuiToolBar.au3>
#include "SysTray_UDF.au3"
WinSetState("Reliance Netconnect" ,"",@SW_RESTORE)
DIM $index=_SysTrayIconIndex("Reliance Netconnect", 1)
;MsgBox(1,"index",$index)
_GUICtrlToolbar_ClickIndex(ControlGetHandle('[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]','','ToolbarWindow321'), $index, "left",False,2)
WinActivate("Reliance Netconnect")
WinWaitActive("Reliance Netconnect")
send("{ENTER}")
send("!c")
WinSetState("Reliance Netconnect" ,"",@SW_MINIMIZE)
```

You can download **SYSTRAY_UDF** from [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/13704-systray-udf/page__hl__%20systray_udf) . If you get previously declared as a 'Const' errors change SysTray_UDF.au3 first lines to :

```
;~ Const $TB_DELETEBUTTON = 1046
;~ Const $TB_GETBUTTON = 1047
;~ Const $TB_BUTTONCOUNT = 1048
Const $TB_GETBUTTONTEXT = 1099
Const $TB_GETBUTTONINFO = 1089
;~ Const $TB_HIDEBUTTON = 1028 ; WM_USER +4
;~ Const $TB_GETITEMRECT = 1053
;~ Const $TB_MOVEBUTTON = 1106 ; WM_USER +82
Const $WM_GETTEXT = 13 ; Included in GUIConstants
;~ Const $PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 2035711
Const $NO_TITLE = "---No title---" ; text that is used when icon window has no title
```